# 3rd Normalization Form --

Tags: database, database-normalization

There are two tables in my database one is named as folder and second is User. Now user has few rights to these folders that which folder will be visible to user and which will not visible to him. By using 3rd Normalization form i normalize my table. My Question to you is that i want your suggestion that have i normalized table correctly or not, Secondly can i normalize it more or not? My this attached image below will help you to know normalization that i did.
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: You might consider putting the permissions (visible, not visible, read only, read/write?) in a separate table.

Comment: @proskor - the values "visible", "not visible" are repeated in the same column. Just like the `user id` and `folder id` are used in the 3rd normalization, you could use a `permission id`

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I know, but why? :) I mean, whether the values `visible` are repeated or `permission_id`s, does it make a big difference?

Comment: Yes, today it is "visible" tomorrow it will be "visible", "zichtbaar", "sichtbar" or "infheicthe". I'd rather join on id's

Comment: I see your point. But which query is simpler / more readable: `SELECT * FROM t WHERE folder_right = 'visible'` or `SELECT * FROM t WHERE permission_id = 1`? The meaning of the first query is pretty obvious, but in order to understand the second one, you should know what `permission_id = 1` means. Is it visible? Is it read-only? Or course you can join on the `permission_id`, but is it **really** nedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You successfully achieved 3NF, since every non-key attribute (in your case `folder right`) depends on the whole key `(user_id, folder_id)` and there are no transitive dependencies.

Actually, your table is in 6NF too, since you cannot decompose the table further into its projections without losing information. :)

Since I am not aware of any normal form beyond 6NF, I'd say you cannot normalize it further.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've *replaced* that table in the middle with the one at the bottom then, yes, you've achieved 3NF <sup>(a)</sup>.

You *can* normalise it more (there's a 4th and 5th normal form) but it's pretty rare to have to go that far.

That doesn't mean more *optimisation* isn't possible. If the only two states you have are visible and non-visible, you can get rid of the states altogether and treat the *existence* of a row in the many-to-many table as indicating visible. That way, your final table would simply be:

```
user id   folder id
=======   =========
   1          1
   2          2
```

with the missing entries `1/2` and `2/1` indicating non-visible.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> A good way to remember 3NF is that every non-key column should depend on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key, so help me, Codd, a bit of DBA humour which explains why they don't get out much :-) The explanation is a little simplied since true normalisation works on candidate keys, not just (for example) primary keys.

That means your middle table wasn't 3NF because its key would have been `userid/folderid` and folder name only depends on *part* of that key.

Comment: how to apply 4th N to it?

Comment: @Zoya, fourth normal form has to do with removing multivalued dependencies of which you have approximately none, it's rarely needed in practice. If you design for 3NF, you should be fine.

Comment: @paxdiablo; the table is 6NF, so he can not normalize it more. Your suggestion (although ok) changes predicate.